# Javascript color picker issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a simple paint app in HTML5 and JS.
I am having trouble changing the color of the canvas background.

I have an input box that calls the color picker. When the value changes it should call the getBgColor() function and update the canvas. However the function is not even being executed and I have no idea why!!

Input Box:

```
 <input id = "bgcolor_select" type="text" value="Background Color" onclick="colorPicker(event)" onchange="getBgColor()"/>
```

Function called by Input Box when value changes:

```
function getBgColor(){
    console.log("Bg Color: " + document.getElementById("bgcolor_select").value);
    context.fillStyle = document.getElementById("bgcolor_select").value;
    context.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
```

When I run my application I can see the value changing in the field as I select colors but for some reason it does not call the function. If I add a character to the value and remove it, then it calls the function.

Any help appriciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're programatically changing the textbox value. Doing so doesn't fire `onchange`. Maybe you could just call `getBgColor()` manually after selecting?

Comment: Yeah your right. I had to change it so that when the field loses focus it changes a boolean to true. Then when the user mouse downs on the canvas it checks the boolean. If true it changes the bg color. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting `input.value = ...`, no `change` event is fired. This only happens when the user changes the value through the actual textbox. You can manually fire it yourself, but in this case you can just call `getBgColor()` instead.